# Steps to create a java project first and add Maven to the project later to build the project in intellij idea

Tags: maven

I created a java project using intellij Idea and I want to build it using Maven. I know that we can create a maven project and do this process but I want to create a java project and add Maven later. Please guide me.

Comment: First of all if you plan to migrate to maven, the project layout should comply to the Maven standard directory layout http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html i.e. java files belong to `src/main/java` and resources belong to `src/main/resources` ...

Comment: @Alexander - Thank you.. What if I create the webapp folder outside the src?

Comment: If you did (which I wouldn't suggest, because sticking to the standard is much better), you'd later have to configure the `maven-war-plugin` to use a non-standard `warSourceDirectory` (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) and configure a non-standard sourceDirectory: `<build><sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src</sourceDirectory></build>`... *But don't do it' - use the standard layout, please*.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ, I used "Add Framework Support" and selected Maven (you will find that in the menu if you right-click the project).  That created a basic pom that I could then add dependencies and plugins to.  In Eclipse, I have done this by right-clicking the project, selecting Configure --> Convert to Maven Project.  That allowed me to start as a regular Java project and convert to Maven later.  It will likely require you to manually clean up the leftovers in the .classpath, remove the lib/ jars, and fill in the pom file with the needed dependencies.  If you are familiar with Maven then it should be no problem for you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes when I chose "Add Framework Support" then it automatically creates the structure for me..